# ASP.NET Core 7 application fails when deployed to local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2022

I have an ASP.NET Core 7.0.0 app that runs fine on Visual Studio 2022.

When I deploy to the local IIS (Windows 11 Home edition), the home url (both the Partner/Partnership) tabs too work fine, but fail on redirecting to other page links Edit/Delete (Both of them work fine in Visual Studio hosting).

Here are the two pages Home, and the exception thrown when click on Edit/Delete links:

[image: Home page]

[image]

I have tried deployment with 'Development' and 'Production' environments in `launchsettings.json`. It has no effect on the exception message.

Comment: check the windows event viewer it should have a detailed error msg

Comment: Please go to IIS Manager and change the application pool environment variables setting. `launchSettings.json` is only used by VS, not IIS.

Comment: It could be possible that your application is having run time error when you host it on the IIS. As it might be sensitive information, it is not showing the actual error and showing the error above. I would suggest you run your app on IIS with the Development mode, it will show you the actual error message. Then you could try to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When ported to IIS, the Console output that I had in place was disabled, as such I had to implement Eventlog to trace the issue.
It was due to missing connection string for ADO net which is used by Edit/Delete
links.
The retrival of the index pages were handled by Entityframework and the connection string was present for that, thus the lists worked.